# Read randomly a String from a Json

Tags: json, swift3

I have a Json file like this:

```
{
    9898989,
    7878787,
    1212121,
    2323232,
    4545454,
    3434343
}
```

Now, I want that the Swift3 code reads randomize one of the id's from the json file (`tests_config.json`).

My code shows at the moment like this:

```
let inputData = try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: "tests_config", withExtension: "json")!)

let configDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: inputData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as! NSDictionary
```

When I want call the function I use:

```
showDetailsPage(forProductID: configDictionary[ONE OF THE IDs IN THE JSON] as! Int)
```

Comment: First of all, that is not valid JSON. Next, you'll want an array, not a dictionary. Then search for `[swift] random array element` and you'll find plenty solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your have a *string* which content is like:

```
[
    9898989,
    7878787,
    1212121,
    2323232,
    4545454,
    3434343
]
```

(otherwise, it's not a [json](http://json.org/) String)

Then, as there is no direct access to specific elements of a String, you need to turn your json *string* in an array:

```
let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!
let array = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [Int]
```

Then, you randomly pick an element:

```
let ONE_OF_THE_IDs = array[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))]
```

(of course, only force try and force unwrap if your data is hardcoded, like it seems in your example)

---

[edit]
If you already have an *array*, then there is nothing related to JSON. Directly randomly pick an element:

```
let myArray = ["2323232", "4545454", "3434343", "7878787"]
let ONE_OF_THE_IDs = Int(myArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myArray.count)))])!
```

Comment: First Thank you for your help.

Comment: Now i have wrote an array like this : 

  1      let myArray = ["2323232", "4545454", "3434343", "7878787"]
  2      let data = string.myArray.data(using: .utf8)!
  3      let array = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [Int]
  4      let ONE_OF_THE_IDs = array[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))]

But now i have a bug in row 2 "Use of unresolved identifier 'string'.

Is it possible to put the first row in a extra file like 'file.data' and how can i read it.

Comment: if you have `myArray` already, you don't need any json transformation. Directly pick a random value.

Comment: Thank you, the version when i have already an array works fine now. Only if i want to put it in an extra Json file won't work.